# Ungrouping objects connected via a vertex

Tags: mesh, objects

I have a few seperate models imported from Sketchup, and I can select the groupings that I made in Sketchup, but there are some groupings that are incorrect (not the same as what was grouped in Sketchup). When I move one group of objects, sometimes there are some unrelated objects which move together with it. However, when I go into edit mode, they are unconnected.

They seem to be connected to random vertices at the grid origin.

I've tried:

- 'L' - 'Make Local' - 'Selected objects' and
- 'U' - 'Make Single User' - 'Object' - "Object & Data & Materials + Tex, to no avail.

I've also tried

- 'Remove from group' among other group options, but they all still seem to leave the objects connected at the vertex near the grid origin, not allowing me to move/translate them as seperate selections unless I got into edit mode.

My question is

**How can I ungroup these objects?**

Comment: To make your question potentionally answerable please add screenshots of the mesh in Object and Edit mode. There isn't any notion as "groupings" in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Your *group* is a single object. You can select the object, go into *edit mode*, then separate parts of the mesh into separate objects.

From [Separating Meshes - Blender Documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/misc.html#separate)

> In edit mode press the hotkey 'P'. Then select one of the option:
>
> **Selected**
>
> > This option separates the selection to a new object.
>
> **All Loose Parts**
>
> > Separates the mesh in its unconnected parts.
>
> **By Material**
>
> > Creates separate mesh objects for each material.

If the parts are unconnected in edit mode (as you stated), use *Separate > All Loose Parts*.

> They seem to be connected to random vertices at the grid origin.

If the parts are connected, You can try to can try to delete the vertices/edges before separating the mesh by loose parts. Otherwise you will have to select the part of the mesh, which you want to separate and separate by selected. (Useful:  'L' [Select Linked])